# SaaS maturity level 2, how i can build configurable SaaS?(Technics and patterns)

Tags: cloud-computing, architect

According SaaS maturity model a SaaS is level 2 if is configurable, but how i can get started in this concept?how patterns and Technics, i can use to enable my SaaS?

Comment: On or off-topic?

Comment: @bigown - I think on topic, but needs some help. @Stefhan, it would help if you link to this "SaaS Maturity Model" you refer to so that we can give contextual answers. Otherwise, you're just going to get random opinion in all likelihood.

Answer (score 3):

**In the Java world use JMX**

The SaaS Level 2 concept essentially allows users to configure their own instances of the software so that they can customise certain aspects of it. From the [Wikipedia Saas article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) :

> Level 2 - Configurable: This adds
>   greater program flexibility through
>   configurable metadata, so many
>   customers use separate instances of
>   the same application code. This lets
>   the vendor meet different customer
>   needs through detailed configuration
>   options, while simplifying common code
>   base maintenance and updating.

By the sound of your question, it seems that you need to gain practice in designing software that is externally configurable.

If you're in the Java world, the Java Management Extensions (JMX) specification allows this kind of behaviour and is well-supported, [particularly through the Spring framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jmx.html). Perhaps explore this technology before embarking on your SaaS project.